# How to detect invalid or undefined custom directive in Angular

Tags: angular

Angular doesn't recognise and shows up with error if an invalid or undefined custom directive is provided.  Basically I want to show an error if non-existing directive is provided.

Lets say if I have a custom directive by the selector name 'myCustomDirective', then I can apply this directive as follows

`<div myCustomDirective class="myStyle"></div>`

But when I apply the directive which does not exist say `myCusto` as shown below, then I want Angular to fail with an error saying something like `myCusto` is undefined.

`<div myCusto class="myStyle"></div>`

Appreciate if anyone can answer my question.

Comment: A directive can have several different types of selectors... what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks Brandon for your reply.  I have updated my question above, hope it is clear now

Comment: Why should it fail? `myCusto` is a perfectly valid attribute in html although it might not be associated with any meaning.

Comment: What if it is wrongly typed like `myCusssto`

Comment: @KaramathMohamed Like igor stated, in HTML5 "myCusssto" is a perfectly valid attribute. Angular will never know the difference. You'd have to keep a whitelist or blacklist of attributes you do or don't want people to use.

Comment: I understand it is a valid attribute in html, but still, is it possible to configure in Angular to emit a warning to report an error in this scenario?

Comment: @brandon  I think whitelist idea works in my case, appreciate if anyone can share a sample code please

Comment: @brandon   How to use whitelist or blacklist of attributes in Angular 2+

Comment: Angular doesn't have such a facility built in. Basically, you'd have to write a directive that scanned every element for whatever attribute you do or don't want to allow. This is going to get very expensive and in all honesty is something I don't think you actually need to do.

Comment: The best thing I can think of is to create a [unit test for the component](https://angular.io/guide/testing) and validate any template defined directives that way. You can then also interact with a mocked directive to ensure proper wiring like inputs/outputs.

Comment: Thanks @Brandon and Igor, it helps a lot.

Comment: This won work as you might have custom html attributes that are not ment to be directives - so it would fail on these as well.

Comment: This can't be done, however what do expect when you add some attribute that doesn't belong to angular, for example `aria-label`